# div align center then left without using width

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have `div`'s inside a `div`

```
<div id="out" align="center">
      <div id="in1" align="left">111</div>
      <div id="in2" align="left">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
      <div id="in3" align="left">bbbb</div>
      <div id="in4" align="left">6516519191</div>
      <div id="in5" align="left">apple</div>
      <div id="in6" align="left">ii</div>
</div>
```

The expected result is a `div` with size=(max inside div size) which is centered. Then items inside it are all aligned left:

```
                         111
                         aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                         bbbb
                         6516519191
                         apple
                         ii
```

I don't want to give `width` to the outer div since I have no idea about size of the items from before.

is there any way?

Comment: unless you set the `width` for either the outside of inside `div` or equal left/right padding for `body`, you won't see them centered on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no "align" attribute for div's.

The information you are providing looks like tabular data. In that case, a table should be used, not div's.

Answer (score 2):

You can by inserting another (outer) container div.

- Outer div container: width 100% and centered text alignment;
- Inner div container: inline-block and left text alignment

CSS

```
#outerContainer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#innerContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="outerContainer">
    <div id="innerContainer">
        <div id="in1">111</div>
        <div id="in2">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Running Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nvMmx/

Comment: gerrnar, have you at least opened the fiddle ? :/

Answer (score 0):

Set the outer `width:100%;`
Or define the inner width otherwise

### CSS

```
.abc{
float:left;
width:100%;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="out" align="center">
      <div id="in1" class="abc">111</div>
      <div id="in2" class="abc">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
      <div id="in3" class="abc">bbbb</div>
      <div id="in4" class="abc">6516519191</div>
      <div id="in5" class="abc">apple</div>
      <div id="in6" class="abc">ii</div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I don't want to give width to the outer div since I have no idea about size of the items from before."_

Comment: That is why I m suggesting you to make it 100%. That will not affect.

Comment: @micro.pravi, `<div id="out" align="center" style="width:100%;">` did not change anything!